# Generating prefix expression from abstract syntax tree

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using a Java library that: given an infix expression `(1 + 3) + 4`, it can build an AST as following:

```
                              BinaryIntegerExpression  
                              /          |            \
              IntegerExpression          op         IntegerExpression
                      |                  |                  |
           BinaryIntegerExpression       +           IntegerConstant
           /          |            \                        |
   IntegerExpression  op      IntegerExpression             4
          |           |             |
    IntegerConstant   +       IntegerConstant
          |                         |
          1                         3
```

Basically, BinaryIntegerExpression and IntegerConstant are subclasses of IntegerExpression.
The library has an abstract class Visitor which allows you to override preVisit and postVisit to traverse the tree. And I can't touch any thing except that.

This is my attempt. I try to use a simple recursion to generate prefix expression. It works OK for small examples.

```
public void preVisit(BinaryIntegerExpression expr) {

        if(stop == true)
            return;

        PrefixVisitor left = new PrefixVisitor();
        left.preVisit(expr.getLeft());

        PrefixVisitor right = new PrefixVisitor();
        right.preVisit(expr.getRight());

        str = "( " + expr.getOp().toString() + " " + left.getExpression() + " " + right.getExpression() + " )";
        stop = true;
    }

public void preVisit(IntegerConstant expr) {

        if(stop == true)
            return;

        str = " " + expr.toString() + " ";
    }
```

However, I have to deal with expressions with the size of more than 100MB, so I have problem with both memory and performance. Therefore, I want to optimize this procedure using a stack. Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks.

========================
EDIT: The expression is the result of a complicated analysis, I just get the result to process it, and can't build the result from the start.

Comment: MB = Mega-bytes, Mb = Mega-bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but I would build the expression into a single StringBuilder from the start.  This would be much faster, but not use less memory.  a 100 MB text files uses 200 MB to load and another 200 MB to manipulate as a String, plus you expressions suggest you want a few GB of memory.

If you are still using too much memory, I suggest streaming the expression to a file.  The generic way to handle this is to take an `Appender` which is a interface for both StringBuilder and PrintWriter.

Hint: consider how you can build the text expression without creating any objects (at least not directly).  If you do this it will be much faster.

The simplest solution is to ensure you have enough heap and use a CPU and memory profiler to improve its efficiency.

Comment: One suggestion I would add is to make the PrefixVisitor class stateless and to use a StringBuilder as return type for the previsit method, and then not instantiating new PrefixVisitors at each step.

Comment: I would make the StringBuilder as argument so you only ever create one.

Comment: The expression is the result of a complicated analysis, I just get the result to process it, and can't build the result from the start. Is there any way to avoid recursion in this case? I tried to increase heap: -Xmx4096m, but I still have problem with memory.

Comment: If recursion was the problem, you would get a StackOverflow.  The problem is how much memory you are consuming in your data structure and generating as text.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a link to what you have mentioned: "use a CPU and memory profiler to improve its efficiency"? I want to read more about it.

Comment: @qsp There is a free profiler builtin to Java https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html  however I use a commercial one http://www.yourkit.com/features/index.jsp